# Trying to understand this syntax

Tags: javascript

Getting my study on via the fantastic and informative [JavaScript is Sexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/), but I came across some syntax that is confusing me.  I've seen the ternary operator before, but never prefixed with the && operator like so:

```
var sex = "Man";

var salutation  = sex && sex === "Man" ? "Mr." : "Ms.";

// salutation = "Mr."
```

The `sex &&` part seems unnecessary to me, and it appears to be working without it:

```
var salutation = sex === "Man" ? "Mr." : "Ms.";

// salutation = "Mr."
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The first operand is a `boolean` expression that is equivalent to an if statement. It would probably make more sense with the implied `()`, thus making it `var salutation = (sex && sex === "Man") ? "Mr." : "Ms."`, which is equivalent to `var salutation; if (sex && sex === "Man") { salutation = "Mr."; } else { salutation = "Ms."; }`. Granted, the `null`/`undefined` check (just `sex` by itself as an expression rather than a value) is also implied.

Comment: Ok, so it's basically a null user input error check (without which salutation would be incorrectly assigned to 'Ms.')?

Comment: I guess javascript is not so sexy after all :-/

Comment: If `sex` is [`null` or otherwise unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Creating_Boolean_objects_with_an_initial_value_of_false) (0, `""`, `false`, `NaN` or `undefined`), then this entire expression will result in `false` and the `salutation` will be guaranteed to be set to `"Ms."`. The general reason to do this kind of chest is because you need to follow that check by _using_ the checked value in some way that would cause a browser (e.g., invoking a method on it, like `sex.toLowerCase() === "Man"`, which would fail if `sex` was unset).

Comment: I just checked this on chrome.. if sex was null, then (sex && sex === "Man") evaluates to null.. not false.

Comment: It is implied because `===` will guarantee the type, and `null === "Man"` or `undefined === "Man"` would be `false`. Looking at the example, I suspect that they had more in mind, but then stopped. To try be clear, the name of this operator is the "conditional operator" and its behavior is the same in pretty much every language that it exists in. The kookieness of the expression is specific to a subset of languages where a variable by itself as a `boolean` expression implicitly checks for it being set (with very specific definitions for what qualifies as it being set).

Comment: ah.. so even if the expression evaluates to null, javascript will still be forced to pick the false part of the ternary operation. I get it :)

Comment: @sksallaj Try `(sex && sex === "Man") ? "Mr." : "Ms."` and not just `(sex && sex === "Man")`. The ladder is just an expression that is literally `undefined`. Using that value as a `boolean` expression is seen as `false`. It's probably worth noting that `null` is different from `undefined` and that is one very big "unsexy" part of Javascript.

Comment: my opinion though.. i_made_that is right, it is overkill.. I don't think the sex && sex part matters.. I tried with (sex && sex === "Man") and (sex === "Man") and I get the same result of false for both.. tested for null, undefined, and for "Man".

Comment: This is usually used in context like `user && user.sex === 'Man'` which makes sure `user.sex` is not evaluated unless `user` object is present and prevents a possible error. May be the code is taken from such a context and modified.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was added after I wrote the comment, but you're exactly right and it is what I meant by it being implied. @sabithpocker I checked the example mentioned; it's verbatim, but I agree that is most likely what the original concept was going after.

Answer (score 1):

This use of the `&&` operator is an idiom that ensures that the right hand side of the expression only gets evaluated if the left hand side is a **truthy** value.

For example look at this code

```
obj.method && obj.method()
```

By using the `&&` here we make sure that the method is called only when it is defined. If the method is not defined, then we don't get an error like we would without the `&&` operator.

In your case the `&&` operator was used to make it clear what happens when sex is not a **truthy** value like `undefined`.